# Missing class of button while changing text

Tags: jquery, button, text

I have button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="dropdown" id="przycisk">Comparative analysis<span class="caret"></span>
```

When I change text in my script like this:

```
$('#przycisk').text('Experiments');
```

My button loses a pointer (dropdown sign). How to keep it?

Comment: It is very good practise when you use as an identifiers only english language. `przycisk` doesnt look good:) pozdro:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI you can use:

```
$('#przycisk').button('option', 'label', 'Experiments');
```

Otherwise, this should work:

```
$("#przycisk")
    .contents()
    .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3;})
    .first()
    .replaceWith("Experiments");
```

It seems complicated, but it works for every case when you want to replace text and leave child tags untouched.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veedxa4s/5/)

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to change the text without removing span.

```js
 $("#przycisk").contents()[0].data='Experiments';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="dropdown" id="przycisk">Comparative analysis<span class="caret"></span></button>
```